# Why i can't push items into empty array?

Tags: javascript

Using an array method, write a function that returns the string elements of an array that have a given length or larger, eg:

```
getWords(['Florida', 'dog', 'phone'], 5) => ['Florida', 'phone']
```

My solution returns empty array. Why i cant pust items into it?

```js
function getWords(array, givenLength) { 
    var result = [];    
    for (var i = 0; i == array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i].length >= givenLength){
        result.push(array[i]);
        }
    } return result; 
}
console.log(getWords(['Florida', 'dog', 'phone'], 5));
```

Comment: `givenLength` should be only an integer such as 5, 3, 9, 21, etc. Only the number.

Comment: It's not an answer, but consider using `array.filter` instead?

Comment: `i == array.length - 1` is `false`, so you never go into the loop body

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Use `i<array.length` instead of `i == array.length - 1`. The second part of the for-loop is to be seen as "keep going while", not as "keep going until".

Answer (score 1):

As in the commentarys mentioned the problem is that you will not go in your loops body because your condition evaluates immediately to false `i == array.length-1.`

However here is an alternative solution how you can write it as one-liner. This exercise is perfectly suited for the `filter()`method of array.

```js
function getWords(array, givenLength) { 
  return array.filter(x => x.length >= givenLength)
}
console.log(getWords(['Florida', 'dog', 'phone'], 5));
```